# `require': cannot load such file -- rack-webconsole (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I just upgraded to Yosemite and I have a Rails 3.2.18 app running on this local machine.  It was running fine (e.g. `rails s` worked, `rails c` worked, etc.) but after cleaning up rvm and re-bundling, I get this error when running `rails c` or `rails s`:

```
/Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack-webconsole (LoadError)
    from /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/cweilemann/Projects/railsapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
```

Line 7 of config/application.rb is:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
```

In my Gemfile, I have:

```
group :development do
  ...
  gem 'rack-webconsole-pry', :require => 'rack-webconsole'
  ...
end
```

If I move the `gem 'rack-webconsole-pry', :require => 'rack-webconsole'` line outside of the `group :development`, the app loads just fine.  If I remove the `:require => 'rack-webconsole'`, the app loads just fine.

Is this a bundler issue?  Or an issue with Rails and Yosemite?

**Update**

`gem env`

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.1 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 76) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railsapp
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railsapp/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/cweilemann/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railsapp
     - /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railsapp/bin
     - /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin
     - /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin
     - /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
```

When I do: `bundle env`

I get:

```
Bundler 1.6.1
Ruby 2.1.1 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 76) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
Rubygems 2.2.2
rvm 1.26.0 (latest)
GEM_HOME /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railsapp
GEM_PATH /Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railsapp:/Users/cweilemann/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global
rubygems-bundler (1.4.3)

Bundler settings
  without
    Set for your local app (/Users/cweilemann/Projects/railsapp/.bundle/config): "test:development"


Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.18'
gem 'rubyzip', '~>0.9.9'
gem 'pg'

...
...

group :development do
  gem "quiet_assets", ">= 1.0.1"
  gem "better_errors", ">= 0.3.2"
  gem "binding_of_caller", "~> 0.7.2"
  gem 'annotate' #puts comments in models/tests with db fields for a given domain
  gem 'debugger', "~> 1.6.6"
  gem 'rack-webconsole-pry', :require => 'rack-webconsole' #default activated by backtick.  may need rake patch task from this project's /lib/tasks
  gem 'foreman' #support to start multiple processes at once (server, resque workers, etc.)
  gem 'rails-erd' #generate ERD for domains. may require separate graphviz binary installation.
  #functional, but not commonly used
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'poltergeist'                         # See https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist for how to install phantomjs
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem "api_matchers"
  gem "shoulda-matchers", ">= 2.6.2", require: false
  gem 'machinist', '~> 2.0'
  gem "guard", "~> 1.6.2"
  gem "spork", "~> 0.9.2"
  gem "guard-rspec", "~> 2.5.1"
  gem "guard-spork", "~> 1.4.0"
  gem 'rb-fsevent', "~> 0.9.4"
  gem 'rb-readline', "~> 0.5.1"
  gem "simplecov", "~> 0.7.1", :require => false
  gem 'puma'
  gem 'sql_queries_count'
end


Gemfile.lock

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/jwhitley/requirejs-rails.git
  revision: f2330104aeca4d193fd5680a22ae7eee85d814b5
  specs:
    requirejs-rails (0.9.1)
      railties (>= 3.1.1, < 4.1)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:

    ...
    ...

    rack-webconsole-pry (0.1.9)
      json
      multi_json (>= 1.0.3)
      pry
      rack
    rails (3.2.18)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.18)
      actionpack (= 3.2.18)
      activerecord (= 3.2.18)
      activeresource (= 3.2.18)
      activesupport (= 3.2.18)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.18)
    ...
    ...


PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  ...
  ...

  rack-webconsole-pry
  rails (= 3.2.18)
  ...
```

**Note:** I've edited the `bundle env` list for security purposes as this is a production application.

When I do: `bundle show --paths rack-webconsole-pry`

I get:

```
Could not find gem 'rack-webconsole-pry'.
Did you mean rack-webconsole-pry?
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this in a new Rails project on my machine. Some additional information would help: the output from `gem env`, `bundle env`, and `bundle show --paths rack-webconsole-pry`. My suspicion is that this has to do with your rvm gemsets.

Comment: @TimMoore Updated with requested info. Thanks big time for your help!

Comment: Could you try with the latest version of Bundler? (Run `gem install bundler` to update.)

Comment: Scratch that... found the problem. Answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you have from `bundle env` shows this:

```
Bundler settings
  without
    Set for your local app (/Users/cweilemann/Projects/railsapp/.bundle/config): "test:development"
```

This means that `bundle install` will skip installing anything in your `development` group (and `test` as well).

Remove that line from your `.bundle/config` file and run `bundle install` again, and it should start working.

Comment: Thanks Tim!  I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with `rack-webconsole-pry`.

Here's the Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

group :development do
  gem 'rack-webconsole-pry', :require => 'rack-webconsole'
end
```

Here's installing those gems into Rubygems system gems with no gemsets, and everything working:

```
$ bundle install --system
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using json 1.8.1
Using rack 1.5.2
Using bundler 1.7.5
Using slop 3.6.0
Using pry 0.10.1
Using rack-webconsole-pry 0.1.9
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
$ bundle check
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
$ bundle exec bundle check
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
```

Here's me installing those gems into a path instead of into system gems, and everything breaking horribly:

```
$ bundle install --path gems
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Using bundler 1.7.5
Installing method_source 0.8.2
Installing slop 3.6.0
Installing coderay 1.1.0
Installing rack 1.5.2
Installing multi_json 1.10.1
Installing pry 0.10.1
Installing json 1.8.1
Installing rack-webconsole-pry 0.1.9
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./gems

$ bundle check
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied

$ bundle exec bundle check
Could not find coderay-1.1.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When it is loaded, rack-webconsole-pry is somehow doing something that breaks the way gems are loaded, making it impossible to load gems after that. When you move it out of the development group, it doesn't get required, and so things are fine. When you put it in the development group, it gets loaded, but then breaks the way gems are loaded, and then it's no longer possible to find gems that are actually installed to load them after that.